# How to call sub blade file inside the main blade file Switch statement in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, switch-statement, laravel-7

```
<html>
<body>
 <script>
     $main_catogery = sessionStorage.getItem('main_cat_name');
         switch ($main_catogery) {
            case "essentials":
                 include('sub-catogery-design.essentials');
                 //@include('sub-catogery-design.essentials');
                 //alert("essentials");
                 break;
            case "electronics":
                 //alert("electronics");
                 break;
        }
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to call the external .blade file inside my main .blade file switch statement, I alrady used 'include' but it's not worked inside the script tag anyone can help me to do this..?

Comment: You are confusing Javascript with PHP. One is Client side and other Server side, you cannot "include" a blade file on Cliente side... I think you want to use VueJs or ReactJs or switch to an AJAX call and get the info you need there, but it is really strange what you want to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<body>
   <div id="main_cat_data"></div>
   <script>
     $sessionData = sessionStorage.getItem('main_cat_name');
          const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          const container = document.getElementById('main_cat_data');
                 xhr.onload = function(){
                        switch ($sessionData) {
                                case 'essentials':
                                    container.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                                break;
                                case 'electronics':
                                    container.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                                break;
                            }
                        };
                        switch ($sessionData) {
                              case 'essentials':
                                  //'view_essentials' my route for view blade file
                                  xhr.open('get', 'view_essentials');
                              break;
                              case 'electronics':
                                  xhr.open('get', 'view_electronics');
                              break;
                      }
                  xhr.send();
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I solved my problem, thanks to those who help me.